# Docker: распространение образов без исходников

Tags: docker

У меня есть приложение в Docker-образов, которое должно запускаться на любом оборудовании, при этом не распространяя его исходный код. Как это сделать максимально правильно?

Comment: А при чём тут докер? На что он влияет? Бинарники можно распространять любым удобным вам способом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> распространение образов без исходников

Противоречит идеологии докера. В образе должен быть код и необходимые для запуска зависимости, ничего больше. Динамические переменные или secrets добавляются во время запуска.

> распространение образов, при этом не распространяя его исходный код

Развернуть на своём сервере [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). Залить туда образ. На нужных серверах `docker login` и запуск контейнеров, образы автоматически загрузятся с private registry.

Для показов:

- `docker login https://private.registry` (логинимся)
- `docker run --rm container` (запуск и удаление контейнера, по завершению)
- `docker rmi image` (удаляем образ)
- `rm -f ~/.docker/config.json` (удаляем auth)

Comment: Интересный вариант, познакомился с docker registry. Но мой вопрос действительно неправильный, дело тут не в Docker-е. Остановился на варианте с компиляций бинарников в определенном дистрибутиве (образ для сборки) и образе для распространения с таким же дистрибутивом и его версией, в который копируются бинарники и устанавливаются библиотеки.

Comment: Да, тогда докер не нужен, разве что только для разработки.